# Avoid pagebreak in merged rows or ranges in SpreadJS

Tags: page-break, spreadjs

I have a table with more than 1500 rows in SpreadJS, with many merged cells spanning multiple rows, but only in some columns.

When printing or exporting, I need to prevent pagebreaks inside the merged cells.

I have not found any setting in printing or exporting options, so I wonder if it can be done with JavaScript.

A solution using ranges would also work for me, because I used ranges to merge those cells.

Using SpreadJS v16

Answer (score 0):

You could try [setting the page breaks manually](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/docs/features/printing/printpagebreak#site_main_content-doc-content_title) using the setColumnPageBreak and setRowPageBreak methods. Refer to the following demo for more printing options: https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs/demos/features/print/custom-print

Hope this helps!